# Export Apache Solr enabled facet settings

Tags: 7, search, features

On the Apache Solr settings page `admin/config/search/apachesolr/enabled-filters` you can control which filters are enabled on your site's search interface.

These settings are not stored in regular Drupal variables, hence, you cannot export these settings in a Feature like you would do with another variables. I am interested in making these settings persistent by storing them in Features.

This would allow to effortlessly switch from a produduction Solr instance to a local instance without having to manually re-apply all these settings by reverting the relevant Feature.

What would be best way to store these settings in Features?

Answer (score 2):

This code resolved my need to backport production enabled-facet settings into localhost. Features are not used. `tfk_search` is the name of my module, substitute this for your own.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Alter apachesolr_enabled_facets_form(), add an additional submit handler
 * that helps us export enabled facet settings via Features.
 */
function tfk_search_form_apachesolr_enabled_facets_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'tfk_search_enabled_facets_form_submit';
}

/**
 * An additional submit handler for the active facets form.
 *
 * Save current settings into default server. Allows backporting
 * production settings into localhost. No Feature revert needed.
 *
 * @see apachesolr_enabled_facets_form
 */
function tfk_search_enabled_facets_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $enabled = array();
  foreach ($form_state['values']['apachesolr_enabled_facets'] as $module => $facets) {
    $enabled[$module] = array_filter($facets);
  }

  // We hardcode 'solr' here because apachesolr_default_server() resolves to something
  // else in production.
  apachesolr_save_enabled_facets('solr', $enabled);
}
```

After importing the database from production into local, while your default Solr instance is still the same as the one in production, go the enabled-facet settings page, and save it (even if you make no changes on it). Then switch the default Solr instance to the local one (`solr`). It should automatically pick up the facet settings for production.

*Note that this solution is good for backporting settings, but not for exporting them á la Features. It would not work if you wanted to automatically push these settings into various sites.*